# Babel 6, unexpected token while try to transplie dir

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I am trying to use `Babel 6` to `transplie ES2015 javascript` files. Two most simple cases, 1 file and files from a directory.

`install babel-cli` and `babel-preset-es2015`, `create a .babelrc.` use command `babel app.js --out-file appout.js.` complete, no problem.

then I try to transplie two files in a directory, one of them use export feature.

```
var shout = function(s){
    return s.toUpperCase();
}

export shout;
```

then when I use cli to tranpile, babel src --out-dir lib
it returns with an error,

```
unexpected token at export shout;
                                                     ^
```

don't really understand what is wrong here.

Comment: It should be `export {shout};`

Answer (score 0):

Mjh's answer is correct:

Instead of:

```
export shout;
```

it should be:

```
export {shout};
```

or

```
export default shout;
```